# How can I build a list of all words that follow each word in a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to build a random sentence generator using markov chains, but am running into a problem when trying to a build list of words that follow each word in a file. The code I've been trying to use is:

```
word_list = [spot+1 for spot in words if spot == word]
```

I have tried variations, such as:

```
word_list = [words[spot+1] for spot in words if spot == word]
```

But each time, I get the error:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

How can I properly add words to a list that follow a given word? I feel like there's a glaringly obvious solution to this that I'm not thinking of.

Comment: is `spot` a string? if so, what are you trying to accomplish by adding `1` to it?

Comment: Spot is a string and I'm adding 1 to it to get the word that follows it in the list.

Comment: You're just telling it to add 1 to the string though, not the index of where it is in the list. so you'll have to write `word_list = [words[word_list.index(spot) + 1] for spot in words if spot == word]`

Comment: @n1c9 that won't work if `word` appears more than once in the input, because `index(spot)` will always return the index of the first occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to iterate over pairs, rather than individual words:

```
words = ['the', 'enemy', 'of', 'my', 'enemy', 'is', 'my', 'friend']
word = 'my'

[next_word for this_word, next_word in zip(words, words[1:]) if this_word == word]
```

Result:

```
['enemy', 'friend']
```

This approach relies on Python's [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function, and slicing.

`words[1:]` is a copy of `words` which misses out the first one:

```
>>> words[1:]
['enemy', 'of', 'my', 'enemy', 'is', 'my', 'friend']
```

... so that when you zip the original `words` with it, you get a list of pairs:

```
>>> list(zip(words, words[1:]))
[('The', 'enemy'),
 ('enemy', 'of'),
 ('of', 'my'),
 ('my', 'enemy'),
 ('enemy', 'is'),
 ('is', 'my'),
 ('my', 'friend')]
```

Once you've got that, your list comprehension just needs to return the second word in each pair if the first word is the one you're looking for:

```
word = 'enemy'

[next_word for this_word, next_word in zip(words, words[1:]) if this_word == word]
```

Result:

```
['of', 'is']
```